# How to multiply these Matrices?

Tags: r, matrix

So I have to multiple a matrix that is a 4x4 and a 4x3, how am I able to do this in R? I was able to multiply two 4x4 matrices (I think I did it correctly), but the same method does not work for the second set. Here is my code:

`A <- matrix(1:16, nrow = 4, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)`

`A`

```
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    2    3    4
## [2,]    5    6    7    8
## [3,]    9   10   11   12
## [4,]   13   14   15   16
```

`identity <- diag(4)`

`identity`

```
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    0    0    0
## [2,]    0    1    0    0
## [3,]    0    0    1    0
## [4,]    0    0    0    1
```

`Multiply <- (A*identity)`

`Multiply`

```
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    0    0    0
## [2,]    0    6    0    0
## [3,]    0    0   11    0
## [4,]    0    0    0   16
```

These are the other two I need to multiply, but the same code as above does not work.

`B <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)`

`B`

```
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    2    3
## [2,]    4    5    6
## [3,]    7    8    9
## [4,]   10   11   12
```

`Multiply2 <- (A*B)`

`Multiply2`

The code above does not work, so how would you recommend proceeding?

Comment: For the second case, what is your expected output.  The first one is elementwise multiplication which obviously doesn't work when the lenghts are different

Comment: The question for the first multiple simply asked to carryout the multiplication of Matrix A and the identity matrix. The second question asked if a multiplication of A*B is feasible, and if so, carry out the multiplication

Comment: Your question in the post is not clear `The code above does not work, so how would you recommend proceeding?`. when you are asking recommending to proceed, it can be intrepreted in different ways, i.e. `A[, 1:3] * B`

Comment: For matrix multiplication you what to use %*%.  For example A %*% B.  The A*B is just multiplying the corresponding elements together and is not correct for matrixes.

Answer (score 0):

In R, you need to use the symbol `%*%` to do the matrix multiplication, rather than `*`.

For example, in your case the matrix multiplication should be:

```
A <- matrix(1:16, nrow = 4, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

B <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

multiply_AA <- A %*% A
multiply_AA

multiply_AB <- A %*% B
multiply_AB
```